# change 'validRange' property after initialization in primeng schedule

Tags: angular, primeng

I would like to let the user customize the schedule (month view) by letting him adjust the header, hiddenDays, validRange...

It's working for properties of schedule (like header...).

However, when I try to change the value of `validRange`, which is not a property of schedule, by binding to the property `options`, it is not working.

My .html:

```html
<p-schedule [events]="events" #fc [header]=headerConfig [options]=optionsConfig locale="nl" [hiddenDays]=hiddenDays
  contentHeight="auto" aspectRatio="3" editable="true" (onDayClick)="handleDayClick($event, fc)"
  (onEventClick)="handleEventClicked($event, fc)"></p-schedule>
```

in .ts

```js
events: any[];
rangeStartDate: string;
rangeEndDate: string;
headerConfig: any;
optionsConfig: any;
hiddenDays: any[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.rangeStartDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  this.rangeEndDate = moment().add(3, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
   ...
  this.headerConfig = {
    left: 'title',
    center: '',
    right: 'prev,next'
  };
  this.optionsConfig = {
    selectable: true,
    showNonCurrentDates: false,
    validRange:
    {
      'start': this.rangeStartDate,
      'end': this.rangeEndDate
    },
    columnHeader: true,
    columnHeaderFormat: 'ddd',
  }
  this.hiddenDays = [0];
}
```

function to change properties in schedule

```js
handleSliderChange(event) {

  this.rangeStartDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  this.rangeEndDate = moment().add(6, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  // this is working (header gets updated with new values)
  this.headerConfig = {
    left: '',
    center: '',
    right: ''
  };
  //this is not working
  this.optionsConfig = {
    validRange:
    {
      'start': this.rangeStartDate,
      'end': this.rangeEndDate
    },
  };
}
```